# Matlab: Using detrend(var) but using the variable referenced in the string saved in 'var'

Tags: matlab

My code essentially loads in a .mat file with a number of data arrays in it. As the user names the arrays in this file what they want, the tell my code what the variable names are through a GUI, which saves the array names to a string in another variable.

I need to perform a detrend() on these arrays before plotting them, however the detrend function references the variable name rather than the array.

Example:
...
varName = get(handles.edit1,'String') ; %'Data1'
...
Load (file.mat) %contains data arrays

Data = detrend(double(varName));
...

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the issue. What about using `varName = str2double(get(handles.edit1,'String') )`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `load('file.mat')` which pollutes your code's namespace with the user data, use

```
userData = load('file.mat');
```

or even

```
userData = load('file.mat', varName);
```

After this, you can do

```
userData.(varName)
```

to access the variable whose name is in the string `varName`, whose contents were read from the file `file.mat`.

You could even use `fieldNames(userData)` to find out the array names, instead of requiring the user to remember and type them in.